# vba auto increment a number?

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to insert a reference number into a cell in excel using vba. I want a prefix text of 'V0000' followed by an auto incremented number starting from 836.

```
so for each row that gets inserted I will have V0000836
Then V0000837
etc
```

A large portion of my code creates a new row and inserts data into it automatically one after the other, but instead of posting my whole code I am just wanting to focus on this one line of code which inserts value into column AA of my spreadsheet. I am using the following but it just gives me V00001 each time. can someone show me how I can get my code to do what I want it to.

```
ws2.Range("AA" & DestRow).Value = "V0000836" & Value + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider an alternative that does not remove numerical (mathematical) functionality from the cell's value.

```
ws2.Range("AA" & DestRow).numberformat = "\V0000000"
ws2.Range("AA" & DestRow).Value = 836 + 1
```

If you require the formatted (*displayed*) alphanumeric designation you can retrieve it like this.

```
Dim str as string, num as long
str = ws2.Range("AA" & DestRow).text    '◄ V0000837
num = ws2.Range("AA" & DestRow).value   '◄ 837
```

Comment: ++ that's the way to go but be careful using `.Text` as if the column width is quite small and the text actually displays `###` then that's the value `.Text` will be returning `###` which may not always be what is expected. Possibly a better alternative to return the formatted value would be `Format(ws2.Range("AA" & DestRow).Value, "\V0000000")`

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks for this but it doesn't quite do what I need, it adds a 1 to V0000836 which makes it V0000837 but when I run my code and create a new row the number stays the same as V0000837 and I want it to go up to V0000838 and 839 etc for each new row

Comment: @liam spence - Try `ws2.Range("AA" & DestRow) = ws2.Range("AA" & DestRow).offset(-1, 0) + 1`. There are any number of ways to increment the number once you are dealing with true numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA, you can do this by incrementing the number each time the loop goes round and then prefixing the V0000 to the front like so:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim cell As Range, rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:A10")

i = 836

For Each cell In rng
    cell.Value = "V000" & i
    i = i + 1
Next cell
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, always produces the same result V0000836

Comment: This will always have a prefix of 'V000', which is not right, since if you have tens, hundreds, thousands, you will always have that prefix. eg. 'V0009', 'V00099','V000999', for when 'i' is 9, 99, and 999 respectively