# VBA auto number cells that contain text

Tags: vba, excel, autofill, autonumber

I am trying to find a solution for the following problem: column A contains names and I would like to keep those names there and use a code that will auto number them. 
Something like:

[image]

I have looked at quite a few examples on StackOverflow but what those codes do is mainly auto number some cells without necesarily keeping the text in the same cell: [vba auto increment a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337568/vba-auto-increment-a-number)
Could you please help me?

Here is the code I used but I only managed to insert numbers, not keep the text in the same cell.

```
Sub autonumber()


Dim i As Integer
Dim cell As Range, rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:A10")

i = 1

For Each cell In rng
    cell.Value = "" & i
    i = i + 1
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? if you don't know any VBA code the easiest solution is copy to Word, auto-number and copy back as text

Comment: You can edit your question and put the code there. But i usually avoid VBA if i can just do it with formulas, like @Luis Curado's answer.

Comment: @iamanigeeit : that is the code I have used, I don't know how to keep the name in the cell;

Comment: change `cell.Value = "" & i` to `cell.Value = i & ". " & cell.Value`

Comment: also if you just want to select and auto-number then you don't need `rng` at all: just use `For Each cell In Selection`

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you @iamanigeeit

Comment: i added it as an answer, please accept if it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
cell.Value = "" & i
```

to

```
cell.Value = i & ". " & cell.Value
```

Also if you just want to select and auto-number then you don't need `rng` at all: just use

```
For Each cell In Selection
```

Answer (score 2):

you can doit without VBA.

just:

- in cell A1 u put the formula **=row(A1)& ". " &C1** and copy to the others

u can create an "autonumber" propagating row(A1) to the cells of column A

good luck

Comment: thank yo! I have the code above, I am stuck on the part for keeping the initial text;

Comment: in your code u justa had to had the column C text, just like  **cell.Value = "" & i & ". " & Range("c" & i)**. good luck

Comment: thank you @Luis Curado . I am sorry, maybe I did not explain very well: in my sheet there are no names in column C! There are only names in A and it is there where I want to do the auto numbering and to keep the initial text that was inputed!

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to @Luis Curado's answer, if you don't start on the first row (say start at A4) you can do

```
=ROW(A4)-ROW(A$4)+1&". "&A4
```

Comment: Thank you! as I wrote above, I did insert a numbering but I would also like to keep the text;

Comment: did you try the formula? because the last part `&A4` adds the text in A4

Comment: I am sorry, maybe I did not explain very well: in my sheet there are no names in column C! There are only names in A and it is there where I want to do the auto numbering and to keep the initial text that was inputed. your formula, for ex, did the numbering without keeping the text.

Comment: uh, you have to put the formula in B4 or somewhere else